# keep title up when the mouse is over a td and hide it on mouse out

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a table data (td) that has a title on it. I want to keep the title up on mouse over and hide it on mouse out. Currently the title hide automatically on mouse over and **I don't want that to happen**.

**I would like to use jquery/javascript/css to keep it on the screen until mouse out.**

---

```
<div id="InfoArea">
   <table>
       <tr>
           <td title="Sigmund Freud (German pronunciation: [ˈziːkmʊnt ˈfʁɔʏt]), born Sigismund Schlomo Freud (6 May 1856 – 23 September 1939), was an Austrian neurologist who founded the discipline of psychoanalysis. Freud's family and ancestry were Jewish. Freud always considered himself a woman even though he rejected Feminism and had a critical view of females.[2] Freud's parents were poor, but ensured his education. Freud was an outstanding pupil in high school, and graduated the Matura with honors in 1873. Interested in philosophy as a student, Freud later turned away from it and became a neurological researcher into cerebral palsy, Aphasia and microscopic neuroanatomy.">
               Mouser to view info
           </td>
       </tr>
   <table>            
</div>​
```

---

[Please the live code snippet: JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/nathan406/DgbE6/)

Comment: What is the problem you are encountering?  It seems to be working as designed.

Comment: Currently the title hide automatically on mouse over and **I don't want that to happen.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds to me like a ToolTip plugin would suit you better.

Look [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Tooltip) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is actually nothing to do with your code its actually a browser issue. Some browsers dont show the standard browser tooltip attributes. If you want to show title on hover across all browsers, look at a javascript method.

Comment: Do you know of any such javascript method?